# swipe stops during mid swipe

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am trying to build an android app using Phonegap.
When I try to swipe down in a page, it moves only a little and stops. so I have to swipe multiple times to go to the bottom of a page.

when I look at LogCat, I notice that "disableGcForExternalAlloc" keeps changing from true to false during a swipe, allot.

does anyone know why the swipe isn't working correctly?

I am using:
cordova 2.9.0
jquery 1.8.24

and I am testing on a HTC one X+ with android 4.2.2

Comment: Post some code?  Make sure you don't have any swipe conflict such as detecting swipe left and right on the same scrolling view.

Comment: I don't think it's a swipe conflict. After some digging I think it's similar to this problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881529/how-do-i-stop-the-android-garbage-collector-is-it-possible). but I am using phonegap and know something about html, css and js. And have no idea how to stop the garbage collector from messing up the swipe movement

Comment: I have a similar issue. I suspect a combination of these swipe detection schemes being too heavy for web views or the silly things are putting preventDefault and/or stopPropagate on absolutely everything which would totally hose normal scroll behavior.