# How can I import java.awt.BufferedImage in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, performance, awt

I see answers to questions suggesting the use of BufferedImages for performing increases that I am very interested in.

[How can I avoid garbage collection delays in Java games? (Best Practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484079/how-can-i-avoid-garbage-collection-delays-in-java-games-best-practices)

But I cannot find out a way to import it because it is not part of the SDK of course.  How has everyone else who have used it achieved this?

I am basically looking for a way to store graphics I am writing on canvas without having to build them totally from stratch each time.  For example storing a drawText() as a BufferedImage and drawing that each frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any answers suggesting the use of BufferedImage in an Android environment are wrong; as you note, it's not part of the Android environment. However, you can gain the same efficiency effects by using a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).