# Avoid String Allocation while using a LRU Cache

Tags: java, android, string, caching, stringbuffer

I use a LRU and a disk cache to cache some images in the memory and on the disk.
Previously I used

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
```

to save the images but as I watch the allocation stack I see a lot of String allocations which is clear to me because everytime i use `mMemoryCache.get(cs);` it will allocate a new String object.

During my drawing of each bitmap i need to use the cache around 50-100 times each frame with will cause a lot of GC because of the short living strings.

**How can i prevent this?**

I looked at other questions on how to prevent String allocations, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484079/how-can-i-avoid-garbage-collection-delays-in-java-games-best-practices) and I use the solution by David for the Debug FPS showing, but i cant use it for this special cache version.

I split every image into 100x100 tiles,
my Cache keys will look like this `pageNumber-withcount-heightcount-zoomfactor`

I tried using a `StringBuffer` but that will not work as `toString()` will allocate a new `String` and I need to compare the content.
I could try to use a int/float with 000 as replacement for "-" or even work with a char[] array inside my cache class, but what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not use an Integer as the cache key and calculate it as follows (assuming the zoomfactor is < 100, too): 

int keyInt = (((pageNumber * 100 + withcount) * 100) + heightcount) * 100 + zoomfactor;
Integer key = Integer.valueOf(keyInt);

This will still allocate objects, but Integer.valueOf has a cache for some of them already, and the objects will be smaller.

Comment: That was the way i tried next, to get a number based on the given numbers. That also looks good, it will cause less often the GC to kick in. I think this is a good way, but one question: Why do we convert the int still one more time to int with valueOf? You said because of the internal cache?

Comment: Actually Java will call valueOf() automatically when auto-boxing in implicit conversions. I just wanted to point out that one should not use new Integer() to convert from 'int' to 'Integer'.

Comment: Thanks so far, that was easier than i thought... I use the formular slightly different with a sparse array now and i don't have any problems so far. If you don'T mind, you can answer the question and i will close this then. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an Integer as the cache key and calculate it as follows (assuming the zoomfactor is < 100, too):

```
int keyInt = (((pageNumber * 100 + withcount) * 100) + 
              heightcount) * 100 + zoomfactor;
Integer key = Integer.valueOf(keyInt);
```

This will still allocate objects, but Integer.valueOf has a cache for some of them already, and the objects will be smaller. An auto-boxing will also use Integer.valueOf (which doesn't create a new instance for small numbers), just avoid new Integer().